# Flex: How to change text color of component label/selected item in ComboBox?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, colors

When I set style color, it changes both the text color for the selected item/component label and the text in the dropdown menu.

> color
>       Type: uint   Format: Color   CSS Inheritance: yes
>   Color of text in the component, including the component label. The default value is 0x0B333C.

I would really like the label to be white and the text to be black. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
ComboBox {
   iconColor: #FFFFFF;
   textInputStyleName: cboHeaderColor;
}

.cboHeaderColor {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```